# 405 Method Not Allowed when using restTemplate.getForObject

Tags: spring-mvc, microservices

I am learning micro service using spring cloud.
One service provider like this:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/recommended")
    public String readingList(){
        return "Spring in Action (Manning), Cloud Native Java (O'Reilly), Learning Spring Boot (Packt)";
    }
```

and one service consumer like this:

```
public String readingList() {
    URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost:8090/recommended");
    return this.restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
  }

@GetMapping("/to-read")
      public String readingList() {
        return bookService.readingList();
      }
```

then I send a request "http://localhost:8080/to-read" using postman, and return :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-08-16T08:16:25.239+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "405 Method Not Allowed",
    "path": "/to-read"
}
```

here is part of my porm.xml

```xml
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

more code:

```
@RestController
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@SpringBootApplication
....
```

Comment: Stacktrace on server-side?

Comment: also: Did you annotate your Controller as RestController?